# can I use truncate table query on InnoDB engine of MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am having a mysql database, previously my table were in MyISAM engine, I decided to use transaction hence changed the engine to InnoDB, Since then I am not able to use truncate query.

Every time I try to fire truncate query it interrupts without popping any error
Does truncate query works in InooDB

Comment: just show me what query you are using

Comment: Seems like google's your friend with this one... What error are you getting? You need to be more elaborate with your question.

Comment: Truncate does indeed work in InnoDB. You need to show your code.

Comment: simply using "truncate table databasename.tablename;"    also tried "truncate databasename.tablename"

Comment: @PankajBhandari try using _delete from table_ !!

Comment: also tried with delete query..... Its also not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got this fixed. Safe Update of table was set true, Just changed it to false and query worked. Now I wonder what on earth was this "Safe Update"